# Is it necessary to include a return statement after my while loop in this function?

Tags: c, function, return

I have a function like

```
int myfun(int *a, int *b)
{
    while(some condition)
    {
        if(condition) return *a + *b;
        else
        {
            some manipulation;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When first return statement in while->if part is encountered,does the control go to the function calling myfun or while loop still continues?Why is the return -1 statement needed?

Comment: Put actual code, this question is unclear ...

Comment: The function myfun will end immediately once the return statement in the loop is hit. The last return is there just in case that if statement is never reached, in which case `*a+*b` is never returned, and something else has to be returned instead.

Comment: -1 is returned when  "some condition" has gone false. Maybe data has run out. -1 is conventionally used to indicate error. However it's actually an illegal value in C for a pointer. If null is non-error, the function should set a flag, not attempt to construct an alternative invalid pointer.

Comment: Why does this  `int*` return `int` values? This does not make sense.

Comment: That is a bad way to do it IMO. I would suggest always declare your return variable at the top of function. And you can set it with default value (or don't have to, but I do that most of the time) and then change it when condition is met. Declaration at the top will clearly show what variable name to trace in your code (and also that this is function and not a procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `return *a+*b` the function returns that and ends. You need the `return -1` because if that condition is never met, what will it return? It is a `int` function so it has to return something.

Comment: Well... technically its an `int *` function, thus its returning of `-1` is terrifying, however it is fairly clear that it is intended to be just a normal `int` function.

Comment: Suppose I took care such that if condition is satisfied atleast once in the while loop, still will the compiler check for the return -1 statement?

Comment: Yes it will because the compiler doesn't know it is always true.

Comment: @AnshikaJain The compiler accepts implicit conversion from int to int*, but not a function without explicit return? Interesting, I'd very much like to know which compiler this is.

Comment: I'm not sure about the standard, but GCC will happily compile a function with a missing return while issuing a warning. It will just return heap garbage. Probably undefined behaviour though.

Comment: That was fun to watch. You both edited your posts at the same time, so you still disagree with each other. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `some condition` is not met, control will never enter the loop and proceed on to execute next line where function ends.

In this case, the function should return some value, as it does not have `void` return type. Hence, `return -1`

Answer (score 1):

Yes Dear , if the condition is true for the "if" statement then the function will be returned at that point in this case . The return -1 statement is helpful and indeed necessary  bcoz it take care that something will be returned even if "if" statement is never executed . If the function had been declared as void myfunc then it would surely have caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `return -1` statement is needed because `some_condition` may not be fullfilled at the first time, so the `while` loop will not be entered.

Therefore some return value has to be provided (-1 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The first return statement is only applied when the condition for it is met. If the condition is met, the return statement immediately takes the control back to the calling function, However, if for some reason the if is not satisfied, then all the iterations of the while loop are met and finally it has to return an integer value since the return type is integer, again the control flows back to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Every end point(exit) of functions must have the return statement(if declaration of the function is like that ofcourse).The code you write is gonna be processed by the compiler so it should exactly know all possible exit points of your function depending on meeting the criteria of the branches within your function.